# Azure pipeline npm build failing for React: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-build

In Azure DevOps, the pipeline fails at the npm run build step with an error in one of the indirect dependencies (check line 18 below). The error is `jest-worker/build/index.js:110 _ending;` `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ";"`

[image].

The `pipeline.yaml` is this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install '

- script: |
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm run build'
  
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'build'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 2):

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ";"`

Your `pipeline.yaml` is using an extremely old version of Node.js. Your question is from 2 months ago, so I presume this is incorrect.

### Solution

In your pipeline file (sometimes called `azure-pipelines.yml`), update

```
versionSpec: '10.x'
```

to

```
versionSpec: '16.x'
```

or whatever your project's version of Node.js* is, and rerun your pipeline.

*You can check your project's version of Node.js in its `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing version of Node.js to '16.x'