# React JS npm run start return error SyntaxError: Unexpected token;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I was trying to start react web server with `npm start` but accidentally it returning

```
/home/azureuser/react-inventory/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:110
  _ending;
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

I thought that this wasn't my fault as it worked fine on my local machine but error on virtual machine
is this dependencies problem of eslint-webpack-plugin and I need to submit issue there or this happened because of my machine ?

My Virtual Machine :
Microsoft Azure Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Node Version v10.19.0

Full error message produced
/home/azureuser/react-inventory/n

```
ode_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:110
  _ending;
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/azureuser/react-inventory/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/getESLint.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Comment: Can you share which version of eslint-webpack-plugin are you using?

Comment: i was find out with npm list, and this returned related to eslint-webpack-plugin

Comment: eslint-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ @types/eslint@8.4.10
│ │ │ ├── @types/estree@1.0.0
│ │ │ └── @types/json-schema@7.0.11 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ jest-worker@28.1.3
│ │ │ ├── @types/node@18.11.17 deduped
│ │ │ ├── merge-stream@2.0.0 deduped
│ │ │ └─┬ supports-color@8.1.1
│ │ │   └── has-flag@4.0.0 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ micromatch@4.0.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ braces@3.0.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ fill-range@7.0.1
│ │ │ │   └─┬ to-regex-range@5.0.1
│ │ │ │     └── is-number@7.0.0
│ │ │ └── picomatch@2.3.1
│ │ ├── normalize-path@3.0.0
│ │ └─┬ schema-utils@4.0.0
│ │   ├── @types/json-schema@7.0.11

Comment: eslint-webpack-plugin@3.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs on older versions of nodejs, like your v10, but not newer versions, like v18. Try upgrading nodejs.

Similar question and answer:
[Azure pipeline npm build failing for React: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72989303/azure-pipeline-npm-build-failing-for-react-unexpected-token)
(This question is dealing with Azure Pipelines, but the root problem is the same and proposed solution applies.)